# Unable to conver Map<String,String> of a class using Xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Hi I have a Class which needs to be get converted into XML using XStream Api ,the problem which i am facing is in collection format as the collection gets converted into   and I want something like this .Following is my code :

Java Class :

```
public class Adapter {

    private String type;
    private String adapterName;
    private String adapterClass;
    private HashMap<String, String> param;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getAdapterName() {
        return adapterName;
    }

    public void setAdapterName(String adapterName) {
        this.adapterName = adapterName;
    }

    public String getAdapterClass() {
        return adapterClass;
    }

    public void setAdapterClass(String adapterClass) {
        this.adapterClass = adapterClass;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(HashMap<String, String> param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

}
```

I am getting following output :

```
<adapter>
  <type>connector</type>
    <adapterName>SFTP-connector</adapterName>
    <adapterClass>com.infinia.adapters.connector.SFTPConnector</adapterClass>
  <param>
    <entry>
      <string>username</string>
      <string>testuser</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>host</string>
      <string>192.168.22.14</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>password</string>
      <string>testPassword</string>
    </entry>
   </param>
 </adapter>
 <adapter>
```

Whereas I am expecting the following output :

```
<adapter>
      <type>connector</type>
      <adapterName>SFTP-connector</adapterName>
      <adapterClass>TestValue</adapterClass>
      <param>
        <entry  key="username" value="testuser"></entry>              
        <entry key="host" value="192.168.22.14"></entry>           
        <entry key="password" value="testPassword"> </entry>      
      </param>
</adapter>
<adapter>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to map an Hashmap to key-value-attributes in XML using xstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816525/how-to-map-an-hashmap-to-key-value-attributes-in-xml-using-xstream)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NamedMapConverter](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/extended/NamedMapConverter.html) to achieve your goal

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("adapter", Adapter.class);
    NamedMapConverter m = new NamedMapConverter(xstream.getMapper(), "entry", "key", String.class, "value", String.class, true, true, xstream.getConverterLookup());
    xstream.registerConverter(m);
```